# Entity Framework map entity object to existing table AspNetUsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I use the following class.

```
public class User
{
      public string FirstName { get; set; }

      public string SecondName { get; set; }
}
```

In model builder I want to map this object to existing table AspNetUsers.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");

}
```

I don't want to remove existing table to remain default fields for AspNetUsers. In class User I don't want to inherit by IdentityUser in order not to display properties for IdentityUser. Is there any way to migrate explicit this entity User to table AspNetUsers without necessity removing existing table ?

Comment: Add an explicit code for migrating old users to new users when application starts

Comment: @DipenShah Can you show some example or reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Application_Start method of your global.asax file:

```
using (var db = new DataContext())
using (var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db))
using (var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore))
{
    foreach (var oldUser in db.OldUsers)
    {
        var newUser = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = oldUser.UserName,
            // set other properties
        }
        var result = userManager.Create(newUser);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            // log error
        }
    }

    db.OldUsers.RemoveRange(db.OldUsers);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```